# Populate ComboBox with dynamic .ListFillRange

Tags: excel, vba, combobox, range

I've had a lot of trouble trying to populate a combobox in a worksheet (not in a userform) with a dynamic range from another workbook.  I have finally gotten it to populate by copying and pasting the range from the other workbook to this worksheet then using .ListFillRange, however, I cannot seem to figure out how to code this .ListFillRange to be dynamic.  The second part of my question is - Is it possible to populate the combobox starting with the first line of the combobox?  I don't need or want the blank user-input line at the top.

This is what I have:

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes("ComboBox1").Select
With Selection
    .ListFillRange = "ReprintOld!$U$2:$U$20"
End With
```

But I want something like this:

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes("ComboBox1").Select
With Selection
    .ListFillRange = "ReprintOld!$U$2:End(xlDown)"
End With
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes("ComboBox1").Select
With Selection
    .ListFillRange = "ReprintOld!$U$2:$U$" & sheets("ReprintOld").range("U2").End(xlDown).Row
End With
```

Comment: Awesome!  How about the second part of my question?

Comment: Part2 sounds like you want a listbox and not a combobox?

Comment: well, I want a dropdown more than a listbox because the list grows every week so combobox seems to be my only option.